# Print content of \address

Tags: moderncv

I set my address in an `moderncv` document with `\address{...}{...}{...}`.

Now I want to use that address somewhere else, how can I access the address?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by showing a minimal compilable example (including the place where you want to use the address).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in `moderncv.cls` for the definition of `\address` tells you where the data are stored:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\address}{mG{}G{}}{\def\@addressstreet{#‌​1}\def\@addresscity{‌​#2}\def\@addresscoun‌​try{#3}}
```

Here is an MWE extracting the data later, using

```
\makeatletter
Street: \@addressstreet\\
City: \@addresscity\\
Country: \@addresscountry
```

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
 \firstname{John} % Your first name
 \familyname{Smith} % Your last name
 \address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}{USA}
 \mobile{(000) 111 1111}
 \phone{(000) 111 1112}
 \email{john@smith.com}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Dissecting Address}
\makeatletter
Street: \@addressstreet\\
City: \@addresscity\\
Country: \@addresscountry

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use them at an parameter? `\cvitem{Address}{\@addressstreet, \@addresscity, \@addresscountry}` gives me a lot of errors.

Comment: @Auroratic In a document `@` is precluded from being part of a macro name.  One can get around it by (hopefully temporarily) treating `@` as a normal letter by invoking the switch `\makeatletter`.  This is later to be turned off with `\makeatother`.  So `\makeatletter
\cvitem{Address}{\@addressstreet, \@addresscity, \@addresscountry}
\makeatother` works for me in my code.